# SSH tunel on Linux

Tags: centos, ssh

I am creating an SSH tunnel with this command:

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9944:localhost:9922 localhost -N -p 8844
```

It works great, no problems. But, for some reason, when I execute this command above in my terminal and I wait for some user to user the tunnel my SSH terminal shows:

```
channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 1: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

I have no idea why I see this message and it's even more strange because all the connections are working fine, they all got accepted. Why am I seeing these errors? I tried replacing `localhost` with `127.0.0.1` (like below) and the error still shows up in the terminal:

```
ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9944:127.0.0.1:9922 127.0.0.1 -N -p 8844
```

Do you have any idea what I can try to check what is causing these error messages?

My server is running Centos 9 stream.

Comment: Run a `tcpdump -n -i lo "port 9992"` on the server, what does it report during those messages?